# Combobox displays any LIKE match after User types any characters

Tags: ms-access-2010

I would like an Unbound combobox located in the header of a form to match or filter by any character (s) that a User inputs. I would like those matches only to display in the combobox itself. Once the User selects one of the choices have the form go to that selection and reset the combobox to a complete list.

I tried a parameter query, but that only works once and does not reset. I also looked into LIKE and CONTAINS , but have had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in the combo `RowSource` property:

```
SELECT [Value for combobox list] FROM tbl WHERE [Value for combobox list] LIKE '*' & forms!MyForm!txtInput & '*'
```

You need to do cmb.Requery at some stage after a change is made in `txtInput`. If you do it on the `txtInput_OnChange` event, you will need to access the `Text` property of `txtInput`, so you would need to change the above `SQL` slightly.

Simplest would be to have a button to be pressed after typing in the filter and putting the `Requery` method in `cmdFilter_Click` event

Comment: Hi, I have typed the code into the rowsource of the combobox and set up the Requery in a separate command button. The results of the Select code does not return anything but repeated letters of what I typed in and does not pull up any record when I click on a selection from the combobox. For example, I type in "BR", I see a list of BR BR BR BR BR in the combobox. It should display all names that contain "BR". I should be able to click on one of those names in the list and the form below should go to that record.

Comment: Could you post your `SELECT` statement

Comment: SELECT [FACILITY NAME ] FROM F01_facility WHERE F01_facility.Facility_Name Like '*' & [Forms]![F01_My_Tracking]!txtInput & '*' ORDER BY F01_facility.FACILITY_NAME;

Comment: You must use an asterisk before and after the string.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In order for the `LIKE` keyword to work you must use wildcards (asterisks) to denote other characters. Your SQL statement should be: `SELECT [FACILITY NAME ] FROM F01_facility WHERE F01_facility.Facility_Name Like '*" & [Forms]![F01_My_Tracking]!txtInput & "*' ORDER BY F01_facility.FACILITY_NAME;`

Comment: I must be missing something. I placed the code above in the rowsource of the unbound combobox, but I am not getting the desired result. When I click on the combobox, a Facility Name pop up box appears. I type in the letter or word to get all the facility names that contain that letter or word...For example, let's say  I type "B"...The return is a repeated drop down list of the letter "B" and nothing more. Even if I select one of the "B"'s , I get nothing. Why is not displaying the facility names ? Is it not pointed correctly in the sql code? Thx

Comment: Looks like you have superfluous space after FACILITY NAME before the closing bracket.